# Get length of channel in rust

Tags: rust, channel

I am trying to get the amount of items left in a channel (receiver and sender part). Like the same way in which a Python queue works.

I need to know this to specify some actions that need to be taken when there are N items left in the channel on the receiver end.

Maybe it needs a counter somewhere somehow? I am new to Rust so it is very vague to me.

Comment: Which channel implementation are you using? While standard library channels don't have a public method exposing the number of items in the channels, the crossbeam channels [have one](https://docs.rs/crossbeam-channel/latest/crossbeam_channel/struct.Receiver.html#method.len).